# Hartshorne Exercise II.8.5(b) computing the canonical bundle of a blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a nonsingular variety with $Y$ of codimension $r\geq 2$ nonsingular subvariety. Let $\pi:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be the blow of $X$ along $Y$ and $Y'=\pi^{-1}(Y)$ the exceptional divisor.

In the hint for the exercise, Hartshorne suggests that we prove that $\omega_Z\cong \mathcal{O}_Z(-q-1)$ where $Z$ is the fibre of $Y'$ over a closed point $y\in Y$. This is needed to prove the main result of the problem.

I am having trouble actually finishing off this sheaf computation. From Hartshorne Exercise II.8.3(b) and the fact that $Z\cong \operatorname{Spec}k(y)\times_k Y'$, we know that
$$
\omega_Z\cong p_1^*\omega_y\otimes p_2^*\omega_{Y'}.
$$
From the first of the hint, we know $\omega_{Y'}\cong \pi^*\omega_X\otimes \mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-q-1)$. Also, it is not hard to see that $\omega_y=\mathcal{O}_y$ so that means $p_1^*\omega_y\cong \mathcal{O}_Z$. This reduces the computation to
$$
\omega_Z\cong p_2^*(\pi^*\omega_X\otimes\mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-q-1)).
$$
Since $(-)^*$ distributes over tensor products, we get
$$
\omega_Z\cong p_2^*\pi^*\omega_X\otimes p^*\mathcal{O}_{Y'}(-q-1)\cong p_2^*\pi^*\omega_X\otimes \mathcal{O}_Z(-q-1).
$$
To get the claimed isomorphism, I *should be able to prove* $p_2^*\pi^*\omega_X\cong \mathcal{O}_Z$. However I am having trouble actually doing this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I am actually not too good with computations involving the canonical sheaf so suggestions on how to think about the canoniacl sheaf is also appreciated.

Edit: Here is the full text of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it might be useful to give the full text of the problem, rather than assuming that we all have the book at hand. Also, is $q=r$? Anyway, unless I’m mistaken, $p_2^*\pi^*\omega_X=(\pi \circ p_2)^*\omega_X$, but $\pi \circ p_2$ is simply $Z \rightarrow Y’ \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} Y$ so is the constant map to $y$, and thus $p_2^*\pi^*\omega_X$ is $\mathcal{O}_Z \otimes (\omega_{X,y}\otimes k(y))$. $X$ is smooth (and proper, hopefully?) so its canonical sheaf should be invertible thus the last factor should just be $k(y)$, which is already in $O_Z$.

Comment: @Mindlack I added a screenshot. The goal is to show $q=r-1$. Yes, you're right the composition is just the constant map d'oh! I'll need to mull over whether or not $X$ is proper in that case (likely not, from smoothness alone. We at least know $X$ is an intersection of hypersurfaces though).

I do not think I follow the isomorphism with $\mathcal{O}_Z\otimes(\omega_{X,y}\otimes k(y))$. How does that come about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one big error here at the start which makes solving the rest of the problem difficult. $Z$ is not $\operatorname{Spec} k(y)\times_k Y'$ unless $y$ is a point - the former is a copy of $\Bbb P^{r-1}$ while the latter is of dimension $\dim X - 1$. Let's get the correct diagram out there first: $\def\w{\omega} \def\PP{\mathbb{P}} \def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}} \def\cI{\mathcal{I}} \def\cL{\mathcal{L}} \def\cM{\mathcal{M}} \def\cN{\mathcal{N}} \def\cO{\mathcal{O}} \def\Pic{\operatorname{Pic}}$

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Z @>{p_2}>> \widetilde{X}\\
@V{p_1}VV @VV{\pi}V \\
\{y\} @>{i}>> X
\end{CD}$$

Following the hint, we can write $\w_{\widetilde{X}}\cong \pi^*\cM\otimes\cL(qY')$ for some $\cM$ a line bundle on $X$ and $q\in\ZZ$.
Since $(\pi^*\cM)|_{\widetilde{X}\setminus Y'}\cong \cM|_{X\setminus Y}$ and $\Pic X\setminus Y\cong \Pic X$ (corollary II.6.16 plus the corresponding statement on class groups from before), we see that $\cM$ is determined by its behavior on $\widetilde{X}\setminus Y' \cong X\setminus Y$, and therefore $\cM\cong\w_X$.

Continuing with the hint, we have that $\w_{Y'}\cong \w_{\widetilde{X}} \otimes \cL(Y') \otimes \cO_{Y'}$ by proposition II.8.20.
By our assumption that $\w_{\widetilde{X}}\cong \pi^*\w_X\otimes \cL(qY')$, we see that $\w_{Y'}\cong\pi^*\w_X\otimes\cL((q+1)Y')\otimes\cO_{Y'}$.
As $\cL(Y')\cong \cI_{Y'}^\vee$ by proposition II.6.18 and $\cI_{Y'}\cong \cO_{\widetilde{X}}(1)$ by the proof of proposition II.7.13, we obtain $\w_{Y'}\cong\pi^*\w_X\otimes\cO_{\widetilde{X}}(-q-1)\otimes\cO_{Y'}$.

Taking a closed point $y\in Y$ and letting $Z=\{y\}\times_Y Y'\cong\PP^{r-1}$, we see that $\w_Z\cong \w_{Y'}\otimes \bigwedge^{\dim Y} \cN_{Z/Y'}$ by proposition II.8.20.
This gives us that $$\w_Z\cong \pi^*\w_X\otimes \cO_{\widetilde{X}}(-q-1) \otimes \cO_{Y'} \otimes \bigwedge^{\dim Y} \cN_{Z/Y'}.$$
Since $\cN_{Z/Y'}\cong\pi^*\cN_{\{y\}/Y}$ because they're both free sheaves of rank $\dim Y$ (use theorem II.8.24 to see that locally $Y'\to Y$ is $\PP^{r-1}\times Y\to Y$ then apply exercise II.8.3 for $\cN_{Z/Y'}$; note that $\{y\}$ is a point and the only vector bundles on a point are free) and exterior powers commute with pullback, our expression simplifies to $$\w_Z\cong \pi^*(\w_X\otimes \bigwedge^{\dim Y}\cN_{\{y\}/Y}) \otimes \cO_{\widetilde{X}}(-q-1),$$ which by another application of proposition II.8.20 is just $$\w_Z\cong \pi^*\w_{\{y\}} \otimes \cO_{\widetilde{X}}(-q-1).$$
As $\w_{\{y\}}\cong \cO_{\{k\}}$ and $\pi^*\w_{\{k\}}\cong\cO_Z$, we see that $\w_Z\cong \cO_Z(-q-1)$.
On the other hand, $Z\cong \PP^{r-1}$ so $\w_Z\cong\cO_Z(-r)$ and therefore $q=r-1$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand where I went wrong, but the only thing I do not follow is how $i^*\omega_X$ needs to be a line bundle? At best, we know it is locally free, but do not know the rank.

Comment: No, $\Omega_{X/k}$ is locally free of rank $\dim X$ on a smooth variety; $\omega_X$ is defined to be the top exterior power, that is, $\omega_X = \bigwedge^{\dim X} \Omega_{X/k}$. This is rank 1.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the reminder :). This is also stated in Exercise II.5.16(a).

Comment: I think your answer actually showed $\omega_{Y'}|_Z = \mathcal O_Z(-q-1)$. But how to see $\omega_Z = \mathcal O_Z(-q-1)$? They may differ by an adjunction.

Comment: @Hydrogen see update.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the update. But how to see $\pi^*\mathcal N_{y/Y} = \mathcal N_{Z/Y'}$?

Comment: @Hydrogen they're both free sheaves of rank $\dim Y$ - I've added a little bit about how to see that to the post.